# how to make sure an integer number is unique / not repeated

Tags: java

program is where users enter their details and they are searched by their social security numbers

i have the program running but i can enter the same social secirty number over and over

how can i make sure that users making input enters a unique number??

```
Scanner keyboardIn = new Scanner(System.in);
      
      //Create objects of FileWriter and PrintWriter classes
      FileWriter PersonFile = new FileWriter("persons.txt");
      PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(PersonFile);

int PPSNumber

System.out.print("Enter PPS Number:");
         PPSNumber = keyboardIn.nextInt()

pw.println("PPS Number: " +PPSNumber+ " ");
```

Thank you all

Comment: Hint: use a String for a SSN, they do not need to be numeric.

Comment: Surprise! [SSN are not unique](https://www.computerworld.com/article/2552992/not-so-unique.html). AND they should never be used as an unique identifier.

Answer (score 2):

Collect the integers in a [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) of type [`HashSet<Integer>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html), and before adding, check whether or not the set already [`contains()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#contains-java.lang.Object-) the value you're trying to add.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep social security numbers in a `Set` and check its size every time you add new item, if size remained same the item is repetitive because `Set` does not let repetitive items:

```
Set<Integer> securityNumbers = new HashSet<>();
securityNumbers.add(10);
int securityNumbersSize = securityNumbers.size();
securityNumbers.add(10);
if(securityNumbers.size() == securityNumbersSize){
    //Item is repeated
}
```